# When to synchronize a variable?

Tags: java

When should I synchronize a variable ?

I think it will just be accessed by one thread; does this mean I don't need to synchronize it?

```
synchronized(variableName){

}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If it will only be accessed by one thread, you don't need to synchronize it.

You should synchronize in a multithread environment when you want to protect a variable from simultaneous update from multiple threads.

Comment: What he said. Locking still incurs overhead, no matter how small. So don't lock if you don't have to. This is of course no reason to avoid it in multithreading ;)

Comment: Ok, but if just one thread can be running at any one time how can two threads access the same variable simultaneously ?

Comment: Two or more threads CAN run at the same time, that is the whole concept of multithreading.

Comment: @user470184 if it's a single core microprocessor then that's true, "one instruction at a time", but one instruction normally won't execute a full operation, neither a full thread, neither a method, neither variable allocation, etc.. then JVM and OS will distribute the time to threads, so many things will be happening at the "same time" (an instant each) in that sense it's like when you eat while watching tv, sometimes you watch the dish, other the TV, but you can safely say "I watch tv *while* eating"

Answer (score 1):

As per your code snippet, you are ***synchronizing on*** `variableName` and you are not synchronizing `variableName`. There is a lot of difference between this. If you want to protect the `variableName` then that should be accessed in the `synchronized` block. Like this:

```
synchronized(syncVar){
     variableName = /* some operation which will modify the state of variableName */
}
```

Here `syncVar` is the variable on which you are synchronizing and protecting `variableName` from simultaneous access.

Also, if there is just one thread to access that variable, no need to synchronize. It can be a performance hit.

Comment: Is that the same as - synchronized(variableName ){
     variableName = /* some operation which will modify the state of variableName */
}

Comment: it will work without any error. But generally we acquire lock on one object and modify another.

Answer (score 0):

The reason for sychronization is when a block of code may be accessed by multiple threads. Using the following,

```
synchronized(whateverObject)
{ //...
 // code to be accessed by one thread here...
}
```

ensures that the code block will be accessed by only one thread. All other threads will block until the first thread is finished with it.

There is no need to use the synchronized keyword unless the code is multithreaded.

Answer (score 0):

If performance is a high consideration, I recently read:

```
void synchronized method() {
...
}
```

is faster than:

```
void method() {
    synchronized (this) {
    ...
    }
}
```

in current JVMs. YMMV